# EntityFramework Include and Join syntax

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework-core

I am connecting to a 3rd party SQLite database. Add I am struggling to get the syntax correct for joining a lookup value to a series of nested Includes. Tables are Company, Dept, Employee and EmployeeType. EmployeeType is a list of IDs with associated Name e.g. 1=Casual, 2=Part Time, etc. Employee has an EmpTypeID that should be used to lookup the EmployeeType string. I have the nesting working OK as follows:

```
var Org= await _db.Company.Include(d => d.Depts).ThenInclude(e => e.Employees).ToListAsync();
```

What I can't work out is how to do the Join to get the EmployeeType.Name for the Employee in the resultset?

Comment: I think you would get a better start if you begin with _db.Emplyee. Then you can use navigational properties to get company in 1 direction and Emplyeetype in another direction